# How to edit wordpress wp_option table value

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I installed a slider plugin and there are settings on wp_option table like this.

```
stdClass":3:O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:3:"url";s:64:"http://mysite.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/slider1.jpg";s:6:"height";i:450;s:5:"width";i:1140;s:11:"orientation";s:9:"landscape";}}s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:7:"slider1";s:4:"link";N;s:10:"linkTarget";s:6:"_blank";s:2:"id";i:2;}}s:7:"general";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:9:"randomize";s:0:"";}s:10:"dimensions";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:5:"width";s:4:"1400";s:6:"height";s:3:"530";s:10:"responsive";s:4:"true";}
```

I want to edit width and height without replacing all of above value. How can I do it? Because of not replace all this code has image path. I don't want change it. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of height & width in that line without altering other character

"height";i:**450**;s:5:"width";i:**1140**;s:11:"